# Returning the last row from a mysql subquery when paginating a result set

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm using the following mysql query to create a pagination array -- for a list of documents -- in the form "Ab-Cf | Cg-Le | Li-Ru " etc...

The subquery 'Subquery' selects the entire list of documents, and is variable depending on the user privileges, requirements etc -- so I'm trying to avoid altering that part of the query (and have used a simplified version here).

I'm then selecting the first and last row of each page range  -- i.e, the 1st and 10th row, the 11th and 20th row etc., determined by $num_rows_per_page.

```
SELECT * FROM 
  ( 
  SELECT @row := @row + 1 AS `rownum`, `sort_field` FROM 
    ( 
    SELECT @row := 0 ) r, ( 
                          SELECT D.`id`, D.`display_name` as display_field, 
                          D.`sort_name` as sort_field 
                          FROM Document D ORDER BY `sort_field` ASC 
                          ) Subquery 
     ) Sorted 
     WHERE rownum % $num_rows_per_page = 1 OR rownum % $num_rows_per_page = 0
```

This is working just fine, and gives me a result set like:

```
+---------+-----------------------------------+
| rownum  | index_field                       |
+---------+-----------------------------------+
|       1 | Alternaria humicola               | 
|      10 | Anoplophora chinensis             | 
|      11 | Atherigona soccata                | 
|      20 | Carlavirus RCVMV                  | 
|      21 | Cephus pygmaeus                   | 
|      30 | Colletotrichum truncatum          | 
|      31 | Fusarium oxysporium f. sp. ciceri | 
|      40 | Homalodisca vitripennis           | 
|      41 | Hordevirus BSMV                   | 
|      50 | Mayetiola hordei                  | 
|      51 | Meromyza saltatrix                | 
|      60 | Phyllophaga                       | 
|      61 | Pyrenophora teres                 | 
+--------+------------------------------------+
```

However -- I can't for the life of me work out how to include *the last* row of the subquery in the result set. I.e., the row with rownum 67 (or whatever) that does not meet the criteria of the WHERE clause.

I was hoping to somehow pull the maximum value of `rownum` and add it to the WHERE clause, but I'm having no joy.

Any ideas?

Happy to try to rephrase if this isn't clear!

Edit -- here's a more appropriate version of the subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM 
  ( 
  SELECT @row := @row + 1 AS `rownum`, `sort_field` FROM 
    ( 
    SELECT @row := 0 ) r, 
      (
      SELECT D.`id`, D.`display_name` as display_field,
      D.`sort_name` as sort_field 
      FROM Document D INNER JOIN 
        ( 
        SELECT DS.* FROM Document_Status DS INNER JOIN 
          ( 
          SELECT `document_id`, max(`datetime`) as `MaxDateTime` 
          FROM Document_Status GROUP BY `document_id` 
          ) 
        GS ON DS.`document_id` = GS.`document_id` 
        AND DS.`datetime` = GS.`MaxDateTime` 
        AND DS.`status` = 'approved' INNER JOIN 
          (
          SELECT `id` FROM Document WHERE `template_id`= 2 ) GD 
          ON DS.`document_id` = GD.`id` 
          ) 
        AG ON D.id = AG.document_id ORDER BY `sort_field` ASC 
        ) Subquery 
      ) Sorted 
      WHERE rownum % $num_rows_per_page = 1 OR rownum % $num_rows_per_page = 0
```

But, a key point to remember is that the subquery will change depending on the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try adding

`OR rownum=@row`

to your WHERE clause (in my testing case this works)

Comment: This will work with the subquery as it is in the question, but like I said, it's a hugely simplified subquery. The subquery changes depending on the circumstance, so while your answer will work in the example given, it won't work any other time. What I need is the number of rows returned by the subquery, not the number of rows contained in the table.

Comment: Then it would be a REALLY good idea to post your complete statement

Comment: Done -- this one is an actual example. The number of results will change with the subquery, but it will always be that subquery's row count that I'm interested in.

Comment: That one hit the spot! Thank you! It's so simple now that you've spelled it out for me.